# iOS8でデバイストークンの取得ができない

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

```
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

内で

```
let types:UIUserNotificationType = ([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])
let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

としています。

iOS9だと正しくデバイストークンが返却されますが、iOS8だと

```
error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "Appの有効な“aps-environment”エンタイトルメント文字列が見つかりません"
```

となってしまします。
何か情報をお持ちの方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppIDとプロビジョニングプロファイルの設定でPush通知が有効になってないと思います。

Project>Target>Generalと選択して、下記の画像のように、Push NotificationがONになっているか、エラーが出ていないか確認してください。

ONになっていなければ、AppleのDeveloper Centerから該当のAppIDに対してPush通知を有効にし、プロビジョニングプロファイルを作り直してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]